# Container will not deploy using AWS container service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

## The problem is that when uploading docker image of service to the Amazon container registry, the docker image does not run after adding it as a Task.

See (https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/)

### Step1: Push to AWS Container service private image registry

docker push 734122228327.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/joethecoder2:latest

### ## Step2: SSH into running Docker instance

ssh -i "containerservice.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-217-248-112.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
The authenticity of host 'ec2-18-217-248-112.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com (18.217.248.112)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:wCeAUed36nKeQjEbSDsYjzq8Z5mpNY4pbcahw2mSozs.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-18-217-248-112.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com,18.217.248.112' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

**|  __|  __|
   *|  (   _* \   Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.d
 ____|_**|____/

For documentation visit, http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ecs

### Docker ps running instances

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-102 ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c90a2116f3ab        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest   "/agent"            About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        ecs-agent
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-102 ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c90a2116f3ab        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest   "/agent"            About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        ecs-agent

### Results: Do not show that joethecoder2 image is running. WHY?

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-102 ~]$ docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
amazon/amazon-ecs-agent   latest              2d99efccdfef        3 weeks ago         26.8MB
amazon/amazon-ecs-pause   0.1.0               c846030090b6        3 weeks ago         964kB
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-102 ~]$

### Problem conclusion:

The docker image that was uploaded using Push was not included in the running container service, when adding the Task was done like the example instructions for how to deploy docker containers. (I configured the Task in step 2, and 3, and then setup the cluster in Step 4) See (https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/)

### Test Data

However, when I try to curl the service it does not connect:
curl ec2-18-217-248-112.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ec2-18-217-248-112.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 8080: Connection refused

### Further inspection:

Further inspection shows, that the docker service that should be running for joethecoder2 is not running in the docker instance that should be running on the container service node ec2-18-217-248-112.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: What did you put in when creating the task?  What happens when you manually run `docker run your-image`?

Comment: If I run docker from MACOS it works fine standalone.

Comment: I do not know how to download from the AWS docker registry.

Comment: The registry is here: 734122228327.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/joethecoder2

Comment: Is there a way to pull from this registry?

Comment: docker pull 734122228327.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/joethecoder2:latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://734122228327.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v2/joethecoder2/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials

Comment: aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2
-bash: aws: command not found

Comment: This seems weird, isn't this what the ECS supposed to do?  Its supposed to pull the docker image from the private registry, so that I don't have to install the AWS CLI on every instance?

Answer (score 0):

[Run Task had to be clicked, after setting up the Cluster, to associate the Task with a Cluster.  Once the Task is running, port 8080 opens up successfully for the task.  Host and Container were both mapped to port 8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZUoW.png)